# How to save images in sRGB color profile

Tags: python, image-processing, color-profile

Currently, I am using the line below to save images:

```
img.save(file + ".jpg", "JPEG")
```

but the images are saved in some other color profile, and I need to save the images in sRGB color profile.

Comment: Have a look at image [mode](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the image data sRGB to begin with? If so you should be able to use:

```
im.save(filename, 'jpeg', icc_profile=im.info.get('icc_profile'))
```

to preserve the profile. If it's not sRGB then you'll need to figure out how to interpret the RGB values. Normally this is done by knowing the color space of the RGB you're starting with and converting.